# Merging files that were amended by two developers

Tags: svn, version-control

I am a single developer learning how to use source control software.  I have read the [Subversion documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  I am trying to understand the concept of a merge.

I am able to merge files together assuming that two developers were working on separate classes.  Does the merging facility work if two developers were working on the same class? I realise that it can be argued that this coding practice breaks the SOLID: 'Open-closed' principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) and therefore I am wandering if Subversion assumes that developers follow the open closed principle.

If a change is made to class1 in the trunk and a change is made to class1 in the branch, then can the branch and trunk be merged?

Answer (score 1):

**Patterns**

Version control systems don't assume any specific patterns. You can use them to implement different workflows and it is up to your developers to use best practice. 
However, branching and merging could be considered fundamental concepts and used by most teams in their workflows. Branching in Subversion is not a very *natural* operation compared to e.g. Git. Basically it's just a copy of another directory (most likely `/trunk`). So you could say that Subversion doesn't even assume that you use branching at all. There is not even a `svn` command dedicated to branching.

**Merges and auto-merge**

Two revisions of a single class can be merged. For Subversion they are nothing more than text files. It won't recognize any substructures like classes.

The merge algorithm will most likely be able to auto-merge the files, if the two changes are **not** in the same spot. If they are, the merge process will be suspended and you need to manually resolve the conflict. You may then manually choose to accept one version of the file, accept chunks from either side individually, or manually merge the file in any other way.

Be aware that auto-merges might not work sometimes. In the worst case, they will merge perfectly and the program is still compilable/executable. However, it won't behave as expected. So it's a good idea to check the result of merges, especially if they were auto-merged.

Comment: +1.  I have tested what you said and this does seem to be the case.  Can you clarify what you mean by: " not in the same spot".  Thanks.

Comment: Commit a file with a single line `Hello, World!` then create a branch from this revision. Change `World` to `USA` in the one branch and to `Europe` in the other branch. Commit them and try to merge the file. You will get an unresolvable conflict, because you changed the same _part_ of the file in two different ways. Therefore auto-merge will fail.